# C# switch case problems

Tags: c#, morse-code

How can I use this code win C# Console application. I am total greenhorn in writeing apps.
I need to create app that converts alphabet to morse code.

In class we use visual studio 2015. We are crating app in C# console applications for windows.

Our apps templates starts with:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication4
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    }
```

Program I found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/morse-code-implementation/
Is:

```
 // C# program to demonstrate Morse code 
 using System; 

 class GFG 
 { 
 // function to encode a alphabet as 
   // Morse code 
   static string morseEncode(char x)  
 { 

    // refer to the Morse table 
    // image attached in the article 
    switch (x)  
    { 
        case 'a': 
            return ".-"; 
        case 'b': 
            return "-..."; 
        case 'c': 
            return "-.-."; 
        case 'd': 
            return "-.."; 
        case 'e': 
            return "."; 
        case 'f': 
            return "..-."; 
        case 'g': 
            return "--."; 
        case 'h': 
            return "...."; 
        case 'i': 
            return ".."; 
        case 'j': 
            return ".---"; 
        case 'k': 
            return "-.-"; 
        case 'l': 
            return ".-.."; 
        case 'm': 
            return "--"; 
        case 'n': 
            return "-."; 
        case 'o': 
            return "---"; 
        case 'p': 
            return ".--."; 
        case 'q': 
            return "--.-"; 
        case 'r': 
            return ".-."; 
        case 's': 
            return "..."; 
        case 't': 
            return "-"; 
        case 'u': 
            return "..-"; 
        case 'v': 
            return "...-"; 
        case 'w': 
            return ".--"; 
        case 'x': 
            return "-..-"; 
        case 'y': 
            return "-.--"; 
        // for space 
        case 'z': 
            return "--.."; 
    } 
    return ""; 
  } 

  static void morseCode(string s)  
  { 
    // character by character print  
    // Morse code 
    for (int i = 0;i<s.Length; i++) 
        Console.Write(morseEncode(s[i])); 
        Console.WriteLine(); 
  } 

  // Driver code  
 public static void Main () 
 { 
    string s = "geeksforgeeks"; 
    morseCode(s); 
  } 
 } 

 // This code is contributed by vt_m.
```

My question is:
How can I implement this code to work with my tamplate. I need to create app tahat is useing switch case for convert alphabet to morse.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the actual problem is.

Comment: If I understand correctly. You can replace your `Program` class with `CFG` class.

Comment: You have a class. Insert it in a program. The template you have is a simple program, it won't work without it at all. Inside static void Main you write, what you want to do with class GFG

Comment: Looks like you already have 99% of your homework on a plate and you are asking us to do the other 1% as well.

Comment: @CharlieMalibu welcome.. the CFG class you copied from internet, it is not part of your template. You do not need to use CFG.. one option would be to take the static methods out of the CFG class and drop them in the Program class. You can then call these methods from main()..

Comment: Note: my above tip was the quick way to get your program template to convert Morse. But many experienced object oriented programmers will argue it is better to keep classes intact. So if you do this for school, take Dzianis tip and drop the CFG class next to your Program class.. then call CFG class methods from main().. and don't forget to refer to the geeks website in your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

        GFG.morseEncode('a');

      }
   }
}
```